# Selecting or Asserting values from search suggestions

Tags: java, selenium

[image]I am trying to to perform some operating with selenium webdriver with java as below

1.open amazon site
2.type ipad in the search text field -- which displays few suggestions to the text
3.perform an operation like select or print the number of items in the suggestions

While I was doing this, what I observed is the html code related to suggestions never showed up in DOM ( pure ajax response), if that is the case how can I perform any operation like selecting an item randomly using selenium webdriver.

Another point is, after typing ipad and clicking on go and then again retyping ipad will provide the DOM having the html code for suggestions .

But I need to evaluate while I type for the first time.

Please provide your suggestions.Attached is the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can always have the element by inspecting over it. Get to the element, click **inspect in firepath**, it will give you xpath or css what you have made in there. Though it won't provide you with html as it gets hidden. So in your case each element has a unique id attached to it. To get all elements do:

```
d.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("iPhone");
List<WebElement> lst = d.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@id,'issDiv')]"));
for (WebElement webElement : lst) {
    System.out.println(webElement.getText());
}
```

To click by index do:

```
lst.get(4).click();
```

or based on text, you can do it by:

```
List<WebElement> lst = d.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@id,'issDiv')]"));
for (WebElement webElement : lst) {
    if (webElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("your item to select"))
        webElement.click();
}
```

Comment: But as soon as I rightclick an item in the suggestions list, the list disappear and I do not get the element inspection.Also, the issDiv would not be appearing in DOM while we are typing in the search field.

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed the auto search suggestions panel is not recordable or identifiable through developer tools.But we still can select the search suggestions based on first two characters typed in the input box.Below is a method in my automate amazon java class where there are 2 methods- one to select product types from drop down and then other to type search text, say"Java" and select third option from auto search suggestions.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class AutomateAmazon1 {

    static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    Actions action=new Actions(driver);
    //method to select a given "book" product category from drop down
    public void selectAllorSingleProductAMZ()
    {
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.nav-search-scope.nav-sprite"))).build().perform();
        WebElement productsearchdd_nav=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select#searchDropdownBox"));
        Select productsearchdd=new Select(productsearchdd_nav);
        List<WebElement> productsearchddoptionsele=productsearchdd.getOptions();
        ArrayList<String> productsearchddoptionstext=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(WebElement we:productsearchddoptionsele)
        {
            productsearchddoptionstext.add(we.getText());
        }
        System.out.println(productsearchddoptionstext);

        for(String s:productsearchddoptionstext)
        {
            if(s.toString().contentEquals("Books"))
            {
                productsearchdd.selectByVisibleText("Books");
            }
        }
    }
    //method to input product search text and select third option from //auto search suggestions
    public void searchforSelectedPTAMZ()
    {
//input search text "ja" in search box      
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.nav-search-field>input#twotabsearchtextbox.nav-input")).sendKeys("ja");
//move to first option on auto search suggestions using keyboard down //arrow key selection actions
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.nav-search-field>input#twotabsearchtextbox.nav-input"))).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
//move to second option on auto search suggestions using keyboard down //arrow key selection actions
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.nav-search-field>input#twotabsearchtextbox.nav-input"))).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.nav-search-field>input#twotabsearchtextbox.nav-input"))).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
//finally press enter to choose the selection from auto search suggestions //and input will be autofilled       
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.nav-search-field>input#twotabsearchtextbox.nav-input"))).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        driver.get("http://www.amazon.in/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        AutomateAmazon1 runscriptest1= new AutomateAmazon1();
        runscriptest1.selectAllorSingleProductAMZ();
        runscriptest1.searchforSelectedPTAMZ();

    }

}
```